# Update Display for Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with multiple combo boxes, these boxes have 2 column list where column 0 width is zero. All these boxes have row sources defined for their drop down list values.

When I try to over ride the display value of the combo boxes via vb code, it works for few of the controls while doesnt do anything for the rest. So I made an isolated code just to update values of all combo boxes(cbo) and again the same controls pass/fail. Here is the code I am trying to work with, can anyone please tell me why I am unable to update some combo boxes while others work fine?

Thanks!

```
Sub test()

Dim Ctrl As Control
Dim CtrlName_Combined as String

For Each Ctrl In Forms("frmNewTransaction").Controls

'Name of all combo boxes start with 'cbo' 

If Left(Ctrl.Name, 3) = "cbo" Then
Ctrl = "Hello"
CtrlName_Combined = ctrlName_Combined & Ctrl.Name & " "
End If

Next Ctrl

MsgBox CtrlName_Combined

End Sub
```

Here is screenshot of the form after code run (All Combo boxes start with cbo):
[image]

Comment: My guess would be that the comboxes that don't work have `LimitToList = True`, so they don't accept arbitrary values like "Hello".

Comment: @Andre451 All Comboxes have `LimittoList=Yes `and `Allow Value List Edits = Yes` , Including the ones that are working

Comment: @Andre451 Also, this hello code is a test, I was originally trying to change values of each combo from within a sub according to its row source values when I realized some combos just dont nudge

Comment: Don't you want Ctrl.SelectedValue = "Hello"?  You can't just set the Ctrl to "Hello", Ctrl is a control and not a value.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I cant find any `SelectedValue` under Ctrl. Also all my Ctrl controls will be Combo boxes and the `Ctrl="Hello"` did seem to work for some of the Combo boxes

Comment: Try with `Ctrl.Value = "Hello"`.

Comment: `.Value` is the default property of a Combobox (and Textbox etc.), so `Ctrl = "Hello"` is equivalent to `Ctrl.Value = "Hello"`.

Comment: Dumb question; you're positive all of the combo boxes have "Hello" as one of the values in the field that makes up their RecordSource?

Comment: @Gustav Tried with `Ctrl.Value` as well, no luck. For some reason the comboxes named cboLabel(&SomeNumber), cboSubLabel(&SomeNumber) and cboAccount(&SomeNumber) are just not displaying values.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Do you mean RowSource? None of the Comboxes have "Hello" as one of the values in the row source list - But that did not stop the first 2 from getting updated though

Comment: Can I upload my access file here if anyone wants to take a swing at it? Should I?

Comment: You could upload to _OneDrive_ or similar. But before that - what happens if youe _copy-n-paste_ one working combobox and one non-working? Will the copies also work and not-work, respectively?

Comment: @Gustav Their copies also behave the same way, copies of working ones work and vice virsa (weird)

Comment: Well, then delete those not-working and replace with copies of those working. Some (subtle) difference exists.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for all the help, appreciate the support! Turns out the combo box had 2 columns (1st with zero width) and 1st column was bound so i had to give it value according to the first column which was a number ID. I got around the problem by working along it but I still dont understand how the same configured boxes were behaving differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help. The problem started when few of the combo boxes did not take value when i executed:

`forms("FormName").Controls("ComboBoxName")="Some Value which was in the list"`

So I tested all my combos by passing them value "Hello" which I know was not in their row source. Strangely so few combos responded and others did not. This was the rabbit hole as all my combos were configured same apart from their row source queries but all had an ID and eName column.

Problem was that few combos were not taking the text values I passed them but turns out that if I gave them Numeric value according to the first column they start responding (what i dont get here is that how some combos behave one way and rest the other way)

Anyway this helped me get past the problem, thought i should share this after bothering you all with it.

Also I am seeing that the question or manner was not well received by the community, would be helpful if someone pointed out what not to do for future references

Thanks Again!